# How do i solve error "cannot find module 'jquery'" in my Typescript build

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, asp.net-core, requirejs

I currently have this at the top of my "ts" files `import $ = require("jquery");` I am doing this because I am trying to use jquery in my typescript files, but i cant seem to get it to compile because it returns the error stated in the title. I am using ASP.NET CORE

**Script Folders**

[image]

**tsonfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "umd"
    },
    "files": [
        "wwwroot/js/player-page.ts",
        "wwwroot/js/playerDetails-page.ts",
        "wwwroot/js/DataTableSetting.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

**main.ts**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "wwwroot/js/lib",

    paths: {
        jquery: "jquery-3.1.1"
    }
});

require(["jquery", "DataTable", "DataTableSetting"],
    ($: JQueryStatic, datatable: DataTables.DataTable, dataTableSetting: any) => {
        console.log($);
    });
```

**ASP.NET MVC Layout Page**

```
    <script data-main="~/js/lib/main" src="~/js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

**Console Error**

```
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:5)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:5)
```

**TS file**

```
import $ = require("jquery");
import DataTables = require("./DataTableSetting");

 export class Player {

        private playerTable: HTMLTableElement;

        constructor(playerTable: HTMLTableElement) {
            this.playerTable = playerTable;
            this.wireEvents(this.playerTable);
        }

        initDatatable(playerTable: HTMLTableElement) {
            $(playerTable).DataTable();
        }

        private wireEvents(playerTable: HTMLTableElement): void {
            const btnsUpdatePlayer = playerTable.querySelectorAll(".btnUpdatePlayer");

            Array.prototype.forEach.call(btnsUpdatePlayer,
                (btn: HTMLButtonElement) => {
                    btn.addEventListener("click", (e : Event)=> {
                        console.log(e.target);
                    }, false);
                });
        }
    }

window.onload = () => {
    var $dtPlayerTable = document.getElementById("tblPlayer");
    var playerTable: HTMLTableElement = <HTMLTableElement>$dtPlayerTable;
    const player = new Player(playerTable);
};
```

Comment: Are you including `jquery.d.ts` in your TS files?

Comment: @Louis hi, yes i did try amd module.. wasnt working that is why i switched to umd

Comment: @Louis if you read the question carefully, you'll see a line at the top: "_i cant seem to get it to compile_". It is not unheard of for people who ask questions on StackOverflow to confuse terms, libraries, concepts, etc. In this particular case, it wouldn't surprise me if the OP was confusing TS compiler and RequireJS.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Right, I did not read carefully and missed that bit. I'm sure you're right about the confusion.

Comment: @ifelabolz please post the actual error message you're getting

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh I have updated the question

Comment: That error is a RequireJS error, not a compilation error. So you did get it to *compile*, you just did not get it to *run*.

Comment: no, do not get it to compile, this is what happens when i refresh the page when it's already running @Louis

Comment: @ifelabolz so then, what's the error you get when you try to compile it?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin the error is "Cannot find module jquery", this is comming from one of the modules where i have `require("jquery")`

Comment: Please answer my very first question: Are you including `jquery.d.ts` in your TS files?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I do not have jquery.d.ts included in my TS files, I have updated my question to show what one of my ts files looks like, the first like is `import $ = require("jquery");` and that is where i get the error.

Comment: Ok, finally we got enough information. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TypeScript has two kinds of modules:

1. Implicitly defined as files on disk.
2. Explicitly defined by you, the coder, by saying "Even though this module is not a file on the disk, I guarantee that it exists, and here are types that it contains".

In your code, the `"./DataTableSetting"` module is of the first kind, and the `"jquery"` module is of the second kind. TypeScript can verify that the `DataTableSetting` module exists by looking at the file system and discovering the file sitting there.

But for `jquery`, TypeScript cannot find a file on disk. So it needs a little help from you. It needs you to tell it: "*Don't worry, TypeScript, that you can't find the file. I will make sure that this module actually exists when needed, and here are the types that it will contain*".

The way you tell TypeScript that a module exists, even though it's not on disk, is by declaring it explicitly, like this:

```
declare module "jquery" 
{
    class JQueryStatic 
    {
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This declaration is what the file `jquery.d.ts` contains. So you don't actually need to write this declaration yourself.

However, here is the question: **how does the TypeScript compiler know where to look for this declaration?**

There are actually two ways to indicate where your declaration is located.

**First**, you can include a `/// <reference>` directive at the top of `player-page.ts`, like this:

```
/// <reference path="../DefinitelyTyped/jquery.d.ts" />
```

This will effectively "include" the contents of `jquery.d.ts` in the body of `player-page.ts`, thus making this declaration of module `"jquery"` visible to the code.

**Second**, you could use `tsconfig.json` to specify where to look for type definitions, by specifying `compilerOptions/typeRoots`:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots" : ["wwwroot/js/DefinitelyTyped"],
       ...
   }
}
```

[See full reference on `tsconfig.json` for more information](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Comment: Really helpful explanation. Got my VsCode typescript working with jquery thx.